# Is zero a valid corePoolSize for ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor in Android?

Tags: java, android, scheduled-tasks, threadpoolexecutor

[The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor%28int%29) says that the constructor throws an IllegalArgumentException if corePoolSize is less than zero.  This suggests that zero is a valid value, meaning to not keep any idle threads in the pool.  Does this actually work in practice?  [This non-Android-specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335702/scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-and-corepoolsize-0) suggests that this will cause no threads to ever be created and no scheduled tasks to ever be executed.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, this does not work on Android in practice, but for a different reason.  Although passing zero for the corePoolSize on Android **does** allow threads to be created in the pool and for scheduled tasks to be executed, there seems to be a **bug** that causes the **ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor** to **spin**, constantly creating and tearing-down a thread, destroying performance and possibly even rendering Eclipse unresponsive.

Comment: Can you post a reference for that?

Comment: @AndrewMao, this is just my experience.  Are you asking for documentation to this effect?