# Thread dies inexplicably

Tags: java, threadpool

I have a Java process that has recently started using up 100% CPU time. Using `jdb` I discovered this was caused by a `ThreadPoolExecutor` repeatedly creating threads.

The executor in question is defined as:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService _scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0, new NamedThreadFactory("OrderServiceScheduler", true, null));
```

The only task scheduled is:

```
_scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {  s_log.info("Resetting order books"); _liveOrderBook.clear(); } }, 
                               midnightTodayInMs, 
                               TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS), 
                               TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The log statement never gets printed (I'm 99% sure that `INFO` level logging is enabled for this logger).

I first ran `trace go methods` in jdb and saw a lot lines like:

```
Method entered: "thread=OrderServiceScheduler-thread-22237794", com.kbcfp.util.NamedThreadFactory.newThread(), line=45 bci=0
Method entered: "thread=OrderServiceScheduler-thread-22237794", org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap.childValue(), line=34 bci=0
Method exited: return value = null, "thread=OrderServiceScheduler-thread-22237794", org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap.childValue(), line=38 bci=15
Method exited: return value = instance of java.lang.Thread(name='OrderServiceScheduler-thread-22237795', id=6388), "thread=OrderServiceScheduler-thread-22237794", com.kbcfp.util.NamedThreadFactory.newThread(), line=52 bci=68
```

So I set a breakpoint in `org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap.childValue` and kept proceeding until the thread stops executing unexpectedly (immediately after the last `next, thread` OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734`isn't listed in the output of`threads`):

```
> stop in org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap.childValue
Set breakpoint org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap.childValue
>
Breakpoint hit: "thread=OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734", org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap.childValue(), line=34 bci=0

OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734[1] clear org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap.childValue
Removed: breakpoint org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap.childValue
OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734[1] where
  [1] org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap.childValue (ThreadLocalMap.java:34)
  [2] java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.<init> (ThreadLocal.java:353)
  [3] java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.<init> (ThreadLocal.java:261)
  [4] java.lang.ThreadLocal.createInheritedMap (ThreadLocal.java:236)
  [5] java.lang.Thread.init (Thread.java:401)
  [6] java.lang.Thread.<init> (Thread.java:652)
  [7] com.kbcfp.util.NamedThreadFactory.newThread (NamedThreadFactory.java:45)
  [8] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init> (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:598)
  [9] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:913)
  [10] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:992)
  [11] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1,128)
  [12] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
  [13] java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:722)
OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734[1] next
>
Step completed: "thread=OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734", org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap.childValue(), line=35 bci=5

OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734[1] next
>
Step completed: "thread=OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734", org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap.childValue(), line=38 bci=14

OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734[1] next
>
Step completed: "thread=OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734", com.kbcfp.util.NamedThreadFactory.newThread(), line=45 bci=40

OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734[1] next
>
Step completed: "thread=OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734", com.kbcfp.util.NamedThreadFactory.newThread(), line=48 bci=41

OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734[1] next
>
Step completed: "thread=OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734", com.kbcfp.util.NamedThreadFactory.newThread(), line=49 bci=49

OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734[1] next
>
Step completed: "thread=OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734", com.kbcfp.util.NamedThreadFactory.newThread(), line=52 bci=67

OrderServiceScheduler-thread-151389734[1] next
>
```

Our `NamedThreadFactory` class isn't doing anything exciting:

```
  44: public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
  45:   Thread t = new Thread(_group, r,
  46:       _namePrefix + _threadNumber.getAndIncrement(),
  47:       0);
  48:   t.setDaemon(_makeDaemon);
  49:   if(_overridePriority != null) {
  50:     t.setPriority(_overridePriority);
  51:   }
  52:   return t;
  53: }
```

As far as I can tell, the next line of execution should be 914 of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but the thread dies instead.  Why?

For reference, this is running on JDK 1.7.0_07, on a Solaris x86 host.

The only change I've made is the addition of ActiveMQ's client library.  My suspicion is that this has something to do with the addition of slf4j (specifically `slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar`, and `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar`) to the classpath, but I can't prove this.

**UPDATE**

I've changed the executed task to be a separate class:

```
public class TestingFoo implements Runnable 
{
  private final Logger s_log;

  public TestingFoo(final Logger log)
  {
    s_log = log;
  }
  
  @Override 
  public void run() 
  {  
    try
    {
      s_log.info("Resetting order books"); 
  //    _liveOrderBook.clear(); 
    }
    catch (final Throwable t)
    {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I've set a `jdb` breakpoint at the `log.info` line and it's not getting hit.  Also, I'm not seeing a stack trace being printed on stderr (or the log4j file). Additionally, I've put another `s_log.info` line before the task is scheduled and that *is* printed.

I'm now downloading JDK 1.7.0_21 to see if that makes a difference.

**UPDATE 2**

This was due to setting the core pool size to zero, as Peter Lawrey touched on his answer.  However, instead of having the effect of causing nothing to run, it caused the `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s `runWorker` method to exit immediately.  The gist of the method looks like:

```
runWorker(Worker) {
    ...
    while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
      ...
      task.run();
      ...
    }
    processWorkerExit(..);
}
```

Setting the core pool size causes `getTask` to return `null` without blocking for a task to be submitted.  This causes the loop to exit, `processWorkerExit` then gets called which creates another thread to replace the exiting one.

I believe the issues I saw with the debugger were due to JIT'ed out code.  I put in a `Thread.sleep` statement into the thread factory to slow down the creation of threads which meant I had time to attach the debugger before any optimisations were applied.

TL;DR: I'm an idiot.

**UPDATE 3**

For anyone that may come across this in the future... There's another [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335702/scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-and-corepoolsize-0) that mentions this behaviour has changed in Java 7.  Prior to the change, having a core size of zero would, as Peter Lawrey suggested, cause no threads to ever get created ([bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7091003)).  A [change](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/tl/jdk/rev/8dab38c07b6b) was put in to ensure one thread gets created, which appears to have the effect of causing threads to get created repeatedly.  This can be reproduced with code very similar to the test case in the bug report:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class ScheduledExecutorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0);
        ex.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("hello");
            }
        }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        while (true)
            Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing to do: run the same logging statement *not* in the thread, just to turn that 99% confidence into 100%. Second thing to do: set a breakpoint in the Runnable code (it may well be simpler if you use multiple lines) and see whether that's ever hit.

Comment: I suggest you use Java 7 update 21 and your debugger in your IDE, it is *much* easier to use than the command line debugger.  If your server doesn't have an IDE, I would install one and display it remotely via VNC or X-Windows or No-Machine.

Comment: The priority only matters if all your CPUs are busy, which I suspect won't be the case.  You have to be root to raise the priority of a thread on UNIX. (Administrator on Windows) And even then it is just a hint.

Comment: What Jon Skeet said. Also, try simplify your problem up to the point that the problem is easier to identify. Make a test project for this. Simplify further until you no longer have a problem, or the program cannot be simplified further.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I've connected to the JVM from Eclipse, but it wasn't particularly reliable (not sure if it's because of the increased debugging network traffic from the rapid thread creation).  I'll try with the later JVM as this seems to a pretty repeatable issue.

Comment: I wouldn't set the stack size to 0. `stackSize - the desired stack size for the new thread, or zero to indicate that this parameter is to be ignored.`  Instead I wouldn't mention it, it can only cause you problems/confusion.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes, will add the logging statement immediately before the submitting the task to the scheduler.  I tried setting a `jdb` breakpoint, but it didn't get hit (I used a breakpoint in the form of `name.of.outer.Class:298`, so not sure if that will hit when the anonymous `Runnable.run` method runs though).

Comment: @SimonC If you display your IDE via VNC this should work even on very slow broad bank upload speeds. i.e. run the IDE on the server and display it to your PC.  If you do remote debugging it should be even lower bandwidth.  Can you not debug this on a machine you are local access to?

Comment: If you have "rapid thread creation" I would avoid this.  Your threads should be pretty static if you have used thread pool.  Try to keep the number of threads in your system well under a hundred if you can, your server only has so many CPUs. (Assuming you are not using blocking IO)

Comment: @PeterLawrey, regarding your rapid thread creation comment, I'm at a loss as to why the executor is rapidly creating threads.  Unless I'm mistaken, the scheduled task should be executing once a day.  Even if the task took more than a day to execute, this shouldn't be causing more than one thread per day to be created.  Also, since there's only ever one task being submitted, I wouldn't expect the death of the first task to cause more than one replacement thread to be created.

Comment: I would not be setting the core size, esp to 0 (see my updated answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mis-understood the problem.  You are suggesting that the thread itself is being killed and being restarted?  You are setting a core size of 0 which is unlikely to do what you want.  I would expect it to either not create a thread in which case you threads will never run, or it will create a thread for every task (I suspect not).

I would not set the core size at all and just use Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(ThreadFactory threadFactory) Playing with the core size rarely does exactly what you would like it to do in my experience ;)

If this is the problem it should do exactly the same thing on your local PC and you shouldn't need to do remote debugging.

---

Most likely you are throwing an error which is being discarded.  This is very easily done and is the usual case of threads silently dying.  I suggest you following this pattern.

```
new Runnable() { 
    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            run0();
        } catch(Throwable t) { // this will catch everything not just Exceptions.
            // log t or print it
        }
    }
    void run0() {
        s_log.info("Resetting order books");
        _liveOrderBook.clear(); 
    } 
}
```

You can define an AbstractRunnable with a final run() method to wrap this up.  It is only needed if you are not polling the Future return to check for failures. (I suspect you are discarding this object)

Comment: I'd be happy to accept this as the case, it' was my first suspicion, and I agree, it's better to wrap a thread's root code in a try/catch.  However, if this is the case, wouldn't `jdb` report the exception being thrown?

Comment: It will if you breakpoint all Throwable correctly.  Don't forget not all Throwable are Exceptions.

Comment: @SimonC I mis-understood your question.  You shouldn't be seeing lots of threads being created.

Comment: you're probably right that I shouldn't be setting the core size.  However, I know for a fact that threads are getting created as there is a specific prefix name being used for just this executor.  Also, as far as I can tell, `jdb` by default is set to catch uncaught `Throwable`s.

Comment: @SimonC It's not an uncaught throwable, it is being caught and placed in the Future object. ;)

Comment: ah yes, you're right!  However, I changed my `run` method to include a try/catch(Throwable) and the catch block doesn't appear to run.